# Center align vertically dynamic multiline text of varying heights in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, text, dynamic

I have been trying to figure this out for sometime, the text will be dynamic but generally over two lines which I will break into  tags myself however they will be varying widths as the copy can be different for each line. I need each line to be equal width which I have got working however the problem is getting the two lines to be vertically center and line height correct.

I have a codepen illustrating what I have done so far. The problem is I don't want  to use dy attribute unless there was an accurate way to change it in JS if need be. Any assistance is deeply appreciated.

https://codepen.io/basswow/pen/wvobNWL

```js
let rnd = document.querySelectorAll("text");
rnd.forEach((txt, idx) => {
  let txtlength = txt.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let w = txt.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let scale = w / (2 * txtlength);
  txt.setAttributeNS(
    null,
    "transform",
    `scale(${scale},${scale}) translate(${50 / scale},${
     50/scale
    })`
  );
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@800&display=swap');
svg {
width: 50%;
font-family: "Open Sans, sans-serif";
  font-weight: 800;
}

text {
  font-size: 10;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle stroke="#333" stroke-width="3" fill="white" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
  <circle stroke="#999" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" cx="50" cy="50" r="42"></circle>
  <text id="txt" font-family="sans-serif" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Online Special</text>
  <text id="txt" font-family="sans-serif" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Only</text>
</svg>
```

**EDIT:**
I have come up with something else that sort of works however it's only restricted to two lines.

```js
let rnd = document.querySelectorAll("text");
rnd.forEach((txt, idx) => {
  let txtlength = txt.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let w = txt.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let scale = w / (2 * txtlength);
  let fs = window.getComputedStyle(txt).fontSize;
  let newFs = parseInt(parseInt(fs) * scale * 0.95);
  txt.style.fontSize = `${newFs}px`; 
  txt.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `translate(0,${idx === 0 ? 0 - newFs/2 : 0 + newFs/2})`);
 console.log(fs, newFs+'px');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@800&display=swap');
svg {
width: 500px;

  font-weight: 800;
}

text {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size:10px;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle stroke="#333" stroke-width="3" fill="white" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
  <circle stroke="#999" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" cx="50" cy="50" r="42"></circle>
  <text id="txt" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle"
x="50%" y="50%">Free</text>
  <text id="txt" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">Delivery</text>
</svg>
```

**EDIT**

```js
console.clear();
let fontSize = 10;
const MAXWIDTH = document.querySelector("svg").getBBox().width * 0.7;
const lines = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("text")).map((el) =>
  el.getBBox()
);

let lastY = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("text"))
  .map((el) => el.getBBox())
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.height, 0);
lastY = lastY / 2;

document.querySelectorAll("text").forEach((el, idx) => {
  let ratio = MAXWIDTH / el.getBBox().width;
  let fs = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize);
  el.style.fontSize = Math.round(fs * ratio) + "px";
  el.getBBox().height * (el.getBBox().width / MAXWIDTH);
  el.style.transform = `translateY(${
    lastY + el.getBBox().height * (el.getBBox().width / MAXWIDTH)
  }px)`;

  // el.setAttribute(
  //   "y",
  //   lastY + el.getBBox().height * (el.getBBox().width / MAXWIDTH)
  // );

  lastY += el.getBBox().height;
});
```

```css
text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  /*   dominant-baseline: baseline;
  alignment-baseline: baseline; */
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="#ff0000" />
  <text x="50%" fill="white">Online</text>
  <text x="50%" fill="white">Specials Only</text>
  <text x="50%" fill="white">for the you!</text>
</svg>
```